# Zoo: How to check if a content item is restricted?

Tags: acl, zoo

How can I check if a single zoo content item is restricted and accessible only for registered users after login?
And after this check, apply this class into a div over in image?

```
.restrito {
    background-image: url(../images/restrito.png);
    background-repeat: none;
    width: 225px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Zoo content items are avaiable in table #_zoo_item. All columuns from this table are accessible through the zoo template files:

/media/zoo/applications/blog/templates/TEMPLATE/reder/item/full.php
/media/zoo/applications/blog/templates/TEMPLATE/reder/item/teaser.php

with this code:

```
$item_id = $this->_item->id;
```

You can access any data, by changing the column name:

$item_YOUR_VARIABLE = $this->_item->COLUMN_NAME;

In my case, checking for the access of the items, and display the `div class="restrito"` only for the posts with restricted access, I use this code:

```
$item_access = $this->_item->access;

<?php if ($item_access == "2") : ?>
       <div class="restrito"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Where:

Public Access = "1"

Restricted Access = "2"